# How to get the users with latest post in a single query in typeorm

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am using nest.js + typeorm + mySql

here are my entities

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @Column()
    name: string

    @OneToMany(() => Post, post => post.user)
    posts: Post[]
}

@Entity()
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @Column()
    title: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.posts)
    user: User

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date
}
```

I want to get the list of users with their latest post (single post)

I tried this

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/User';
import { Post } from './entities/Post';

const usersWithPosts = await getRepository(User)
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'user.post', // Map the 'post' property of the 'user' entity
    Post,        // Target entity
    'post',      // Alias for the 'post' entity
    'user.id = post.userId', // ON condition for the join
    qb => qb.orderBy('post.created_at', 'DESC') // Order posts here
  )
  .orderBy('user.name', 'ASC') // Order users here
  .getMany();
```

but it is not ordering the posts by DESC

I am looking for a solution in typeorm query only not in raw sql.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject `User` repository and use it to query for data.

Injecting the repository in the constructor of your service file would look like:

```
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepo: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```

You can then query for the list of users with their latest post(single post) as (have updated your query slightly):

```
  const usersWithPosts = await this.userRepo
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndMapOne(
       'user.post', 
        Post,     
        'post',      
        'user.id = post.userId', 
      )
    .orderBy('user.name', 'ASC') 
    .orderBy("post.created_at", 'DESC')
    .getMany();
```

This query should return the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

By using a custom condition directly on the `ON` for the `JOIN`clause can be very powerful:

```
const usersWithPosts = await getRepository(User)
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
  'user.post',
  Post,
  'post',
  `(post.id = (SELECT id FROM post WHERE post.userId = user.id ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC LIMIT 1))`,
  )
  .orderBy('user.name', 'ASC')
  .getMany();
```

Just make sure that the database is correctly indexed on `post.userId` and you won't be facing performance issues.
Furthermore, if a `COVERING INDEX` (Index involving all columns involved in the query, in this case, `post.userId`and `post.createdAt`) is used for the query, the Database Engine will be able to satisfy the query using only the index (very powerful) and will not even need to query the actual table resulting in a very performant query.